# How to get a user's online activity status (Away or Active) via Rest API (Google Chat)

Tags: google-hangouts

This must be a FAQ but I am new to google apis. I tried to play with the Rest APIs but its not clear to to get the online status of a user. Tried https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get? but not getting anything back. Should I use members, users or people APIs?

Assume I have a user@gmail.com already as a chat partner. I want to have a way to check if the user is Active via this Rest API without me showing as Active (what would happen if I just use the Gmail interface to check manually).

Thanks,
Andy